# SQL-выборка из таблицы, созданной другим SELECT

Tags: sql

Есть вот такая нехитрая табличка.

[image]

Задача - сформировать список дисциплин с максимальным количеством семестров. Вопрос вот в чем, предположим, я пишу, для начала, вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT [name_subject] ,COUNT(*) AS [semesters] FROM [subject]
GROUP BY [name_subject]
```

А теперь хочу найти максимальное количество семестров для определенной дисциплины (в нашем случае 2). Пишу:

```
SELECT MAX([semesters]) FROM ( подзапрос выше )
```

Но выдается почему-то ошибка `Invalid column name 'semesters'`. Можно ли как-то сделать выборку определенных столбцов из таблицы, которая сама сгенерирована другим select?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно присвоить подзапросу псевдоним:

```
select max(a.semesters) from
(
 select name_subject, count(*) as semesters
 from subject
 group by name_subject
) as a
 group by a.name_subject;
```

и тогда вы сможете ссылаться на имена полей подзапроса.